# Multiple command line inputs

Tags: c#, command-line

I am having a bit of trouble running multiple conditions through a command line argument. I have a program that makes XML files based on information found in Excel files. The main issue i am having is that when i run the program through an auto scheduling tool it reads each file as a one whole string, instead of "File 1" "File 2" it is reading it as "File1File2". This is the code for the command line:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "";
    string output = "";


        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (string s in args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
            input = args[0];
            output = args[1];
        }
}
```

I wondered if there was a way, im aware of methods such as split string but the implementation is what i am fuzzy on

Comment: You could split on space, but what if the file name has a space in it?  The real issue is why the file names are not being passed as separate arguments.

Comment: As juharr already suggested, the problem seems to be the command line and not the code. Can you post the command line you use?

Comment: Am I right in thinking the args Length is 1 here? If that is the case its nothing wrong with your program and sounds like the scheduling tool is wrong/misconfigured

Comment: Hi everyone. Now my first initial idea was that it was the scheduling tool. @juharr the file names will not have spaces, the command line is literally names of files whoch keep the same naming convention.

Comment: @Nonagon notice that args[0] will **ALWAYS** give you the path of the exe file in command line applications

Comment: Is that always the case? for example if you were to add the argument parameters in a shortcut executable?

Comment: The args[0] is the EXE's path, all other parameters (even on shortcuts) will be available from args[1] on

Comment: Now that is strange because i have been able to run my program on the basis tha sub zero is the file name, really sorry for the confusion here @cFrozenDeath

Comment: What scheduling tool you use? With 'at' I never experienced any problem with parameters. The filenames come from a pattern?

Comment: If you pass the filenames sourrounded by double-quotes (") you won't have any problem with spaces, as they are taken as a single parameter

Comment: @PeterKrassoi I use Visualcron: http://www.visualcron.com/ the filenames are just generic datetime files which i have compensated for

Comment: @cFrozenDeath so, will i have to change my code to compensate for the double quotes or is that taken into account?

Comment: @Nonagon No change is needed in your code except for taking arguments from args[1] onwards

Comment: @cFrozenDeath: _"args[0] will ALWAYS give you the path of the exe file"_ -- that is not true at all. You are confusing the Windows process command line API with the .NET command line API. By the time your C# program gets the `args` parameter list, the exe name is not present.

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to know precisely what you're doing wrong. However, if your file names (or any other command line argument for that matter) have spaces, you need to quote the entire argument, i.e. `myProgram.exe "File 1" "File 2"`. There are lots of questions on Stack Overflow discussing use of command line arguments for .NET programs; please do a search and read the relevant, previously-asked questions.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Hi Peter, I did plenty of research and unforunately it did not yield any answers to my specific dillema. As you can see from the comment section in this thread, it is obviously a topic which is in need of discussion. I appreciate your feedback though

Comment: I can see from the comments that everyone else, except cFrozenDeath, understands that your problem lies not in the program but in the component that is starting your program, i.e. in the configuration of the command line arguments themselves. There is nothing in the comments that suggests this is a topic which is in need of discussion, and a great deal of evidence in the comments that shows that _you_ need to investigate how command lines arguments work from _outside_ the program (i.e. how to specify them correctly), and how your task scheduler is providing the command line arguments.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Hi Peter, forgive me for coming on to a website and asking a question that i thought was trivial. I will go back to studying for the next 2 years to get a full grasp of the problem instead of asking for advice. Do you have any Books or blogs that would be beneficial for this kind of topic?